# Spring Boot игнорирует CSS / JS при загрузке страницы

Tags: java, css, spring-boot, mustache

Моя страница (order.mustache) использует несколько стилей CSS (внешних и локальных), изображения, фоновое видео и JS-элемент. 
БОльшая часть оформления страницы описана в style.css, который располагается в директории "resourses/static/css".

При запуске страницы через Chrome как HTML-документ - она отображается корректно. Но если я запускаю её через Spring Boot 
(как mustache-страницу) - все локальные стили, изображения, JS и даже youtube-видео игнорируются.

Консоль браузера указывает на ошибку 
"Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8080/static/css/style.css"."
На вкладке Response панели разработчика Chrome style.css отображается, как копия страницы order.mustache. 
На вкладке Headers её тип - text/html.

Я не могу понять, на каком моменте происходят эти изменения, и что мне поменять, чтобы страница заработала полноценно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

HTML:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>...</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link href="../static/css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,100,500,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type="text/css">
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>

</head>
```

Controller:

```
@GetMapping
public String main(Map<String, Object> model) {
    Iterable<Client> clients = repo.findAll();
    model.put("clients", clients);
    return "order";
}

@PostMapping
public String add(@RequestParam String firstName, @RequestParam String lastName, @RequestParam String nationality,
                  @RequestParam String sex, @RequestParam(name = "birthDate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
                              Date birthDate, @RequestParam long passNumber, Map<String, Object> model) {
    Client client = new Client(firstName, lastName, nationality, sex, birthDate, passNumber);
    repo.save(client);

    Iterable<Client> clients = repo.findAll();
    model.put("clients", client);

    return "order";
}
```

Main:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

@Bean
public ViewResolver getViewResolver(ResourceLoader resourceLoader) {
    MustacheViewResolver mustacheViewResolver
            = new MustacheViewResolver();
    mustacheViewResolver.setPrefix("templates/");
    mustacheViewResolver.setSuffix(".mustache");
    mustacheViewResolver.setCache(false);

    return mustacheViewResolver;
}
```

Comment: Скорее всего достаточно будет объявить css так - href="/css/style.css", то же касается и остальных ресурсов

Comment: Да, так тоже работает при HTML загрузке, но на Spring никак не влияет - проблема остаётся. Я пробовал длинные пути, короткие, со слешем, без слеша - не работает через спринг. 

Скорее всего, проблема в контроллере или getViewResolver.

Comment: Пардон, не обратил внимания, а Вы не используете никакой шаблонизатор, просто HTML?

Comment: Использую mustache. Возможно, именно при изменении расширения страницы с .html на .mustache css и отваливается, но у этого шаблонизатора заявлена поддержка стилей и js.

Comment: немного гугла - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21203402/css-not-loading-in-spring-boot

Comment: Ему рекомендуют сменить директорию на /resources/static/css, т.к. Спринг ищет файлы именно там. У меня она как раз такая же. Дальше пример viewResolver для Thymeleaf, а у меня Mustache. 

Я все эти вопросы уже проштудировал.

Comment: Вы были правы, не на всех ресурсах я короткую ссылку применял, отсюда и проблемы с версткой. Пожалуйста, напишите первый комментарий как ответ, чтобы я мог его пометить как решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего достаточно будет объявить css так - href="/css/style.css", то же касается и остальных ресурсов